# Joomla: homepage url

Tags: joomla

Joomla requires that home page was linked with some component.

So, if i link menu item of homepage to some article, i get a url like:

"**index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=68&Itemid=464**" on frontend.

How to link homepage to "/" ?

**UPD:** 
Joomla verion 1.7
Maybe, i not accurately explained.
I link home menu item with some article.
When i go to www.mysite.com - all fine, choosen article is shown on homepage. 
But then the home menu item on frontend became "**index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=68&Itemid=464**", not just '/'

Answer (score 2):

You must use the default Joomla format for setting something as the "home" page.  in 2.5 (since you failed to tell us which version you're running) you do this by using 'featured articles'.  By default, any featured article is displayed on the homepage.

In older versions (1.5) you must mark it to display on the 'front page'

In doing that when you go to http://www.yoursite.com/  - you will see the articles listed as 'featured' or 'front page' articles.  You can adjust how they display by using the front page or featured article manager.

I apologize if I've misunderstood your question - but hope this helps.  It also looks like you don't have SEF URL's turned on - you may want to look into that.  Regardless your front page will display without any additional URL stuff if you use the methods outlined above.

Answer (score 0):

In your menu manager (backend), create a new entry for 1 article and select it in the list. After that, just define this new menu entry as default (or homepage).

This article will be the default homepage of your website and will be accessible via www.yoursite.com/